# Analyzing categorical data: a meaningful way to depict some sort of mean tendency for every group of data

Tags: regression, categorical-data, spss, biostatistics

I'm in the middle of writing my thesis (undergraduate in biology) and not very keen on statistics. I have a bunch of categorical data that I've collected some time now that have to do with the daily life of stable horses. Six of them to be exact, three that perform stereotypies and three normal ones. The goal is to find if there are crucial differences between the two groups concerning their daily routines and probably what cause the stereotypers to stereotype more that doesn't affect the "normal" horses.

Τo give an example of the data that have being collected, every day for roughly six hours between 5 minutes intervals I was recording the behavior of each horse in this exact time plus some other facts that could be affecting it (e.g. proximity of a person in comparison with the horse, location of the horse etc etc). I was collecting data for 3 to 5 days for every horse. So, making the long story short I would like to ask if there's a meaningful way to find the "behavioral mean" of all these days for each horse and then compare them to see the differences. By "behavioral mean" off all the days, I mean average behavior of a horse that can be extracted from a number of days of behavioral data. 
In other words, I  want to depict somehow an average day of every horse's behavior but I don't know how considering the data are categorical and the general notion is that you can't find the mean of categorical data. In my case though I'm asking if it's meaningful to find the average of every count between let's say five days and present it as the average daily behavior of every horse.

By the way I'm using SPPS (ver21) so I'll appreciate it if any suggestions to be SPSS orientated or friendly. **I could post part of my data if anyone wants in order to have a better idea of what I'm talking about.** Pardon me for the length of the inquiry but I was trying to be as comprehensible as possible. Thank you in advance

Comment: The obvious measure of central tendency would be the mode. Does that suit your scientific question?

Comment: @mdewey I wish it could be that simple. The think is I want to depict in a diagram for example, the average behavior of a horse that results from 5 days of data let's say. But I don't know how to find a "mean" in categorical data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood you correctly and your behavior variables are categorical, then instead of average maybe you can think of counting how many times that specific behavior happened of the total number of behaviors recorded during that 6 days and then instead of testing for mean differences you will need to test for proportion differences.

This is done via crosstabs and chi-square test to find the significant differences within SPSS. This might help to take you through the steps: http://www.math.hope.edu/stats/SPSS.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment @RomRom . If you could point me out a method that I could use to compare the proportions I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Biocurious updated my response above to include more details and a link to an example.